# I cannot type letter ‘ç’ a with English (US, alt. Intl.)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I cannot type letter ‘ç’ (’+c) with English (US, alt. Intl.) keyboard, the letter ‘ć’ coming out instead.
Its  working fine before I upgrade the systems weeks ago.
I try to change the keyboard layout but I can't find a layout with ‘ç’ by compose (’+c), my keyboard and my system are English(US).

Answer (score 4):

In the US International keyboard, you can type "ç" by hitting <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>. <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> is your right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

The <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key hides a lot of international characters: combined with <kbd>c</kbd> it delivers the copyright symbol: ©.

As you discovered, the dead keys, i.e. <kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd> deliver accents on letters.

Comment: AltGr stands for “Alternate Graphic”, not Green https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#Meaning

Comment: @arielCo Thanks for pointing this out, and Martin Thornton for having applied corrected already

Answer (score 3):

with the <kbd>Compose</kbd> key set and with an English (UK) keyboard, pressing <kbd>Compose</kbd> then <kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) in succession creates the cedilla character `ç`.

Note that the 3 key presses "latch" (i.e. you don't need to  hold the keys) so there is no need for finger Olympics in order to achieve the successive key presses.

Comment: I sorry, I'm a newbie, but what is COMPOSE key?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your /etc/environment

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
```

You may also need to add the cedilla module to the English language, in my case it came by default:

https://superuser.com/a/1235405